# Not getting response in retrofit call?

Tags: android, response, retrofit2

My Response Call:

```
public void getFeed() {

    if (ApiClient.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity()))
    {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage(getActivity().getString(R.string.txt_please_wait));

        progressDialog.show();



        Call<List<ApiOrderListBean.DataBean.OrdersBean.AssignToBean>> call = ApiClient.getAPIService().getAllData();


        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ApiOrderListBean.DataBean.OrdersBean.AssignToBean>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ApiOrderListBean.DataBean.OrdersBean.AssignToBean>> call, Response<List<ApiOrderListBean.DataBean.OrdersBean.AssignToBean>> response)
            {

                if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();

                }

                 List<ApiOrderListBean.DataBean.OrdersBean.AssignToBean > list = response.body();

                for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++)
                {
                    ApiOrderListBean.DataBean.OrdersBean.AssignToBean toBean= list.get(i);
                    SaveIntoDatabase task = new SaveIntoDatabase();
                    task.execute(toBean);
                    LinearLayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                    mOrderAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterOrder(list);
                    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mOrderAdapter);

                }




                Log.d(TAG, "layout skkiped" + response.message());


            }

            @Override

            public void onFailure(Call<List<ApiOrderListBean.DataBean.OrdersBean.AssignToBean >> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }


}
```

POJO is diff but if i want ContactDetailBean instead it will be same as AssignToBean:

```
public class ManufacturerList extends BaseResponse
{

private String message;
private boolean status;
private DataBean data;
 public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}


public DataBean getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(DataBean data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public static class DataBean {


    private Object deletedManufacturers;
    private List<ManufacturersBean> manufacturers;

    public Object getDeletedManufacturers() {
        return deletedManufacturers;
    }

    public void setDeletedManufacturers(Object deletedManufacturers) {
        this.deletedManufacturers = deletedManufacturers;
    }

    public List<ManufacturersBean> getManufacturers() {
        return manufacturers;
    }

    public void setManufacturers(List<ManufacturersBean> manufacturers) {
        this.manufacturers = manufacturers;
    }

    public static class ManufacturersBean {

        private int id;
        private ContactDetailBean contactDetail;
        private int createdBy;
        private String name;
        private String lastUpdated;
        private String dateCreated;
        private String code;
        private boolean deleted;
        private int updatedBy;
        private List<Integer> categories;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public ContactDetailBean getContactDetail() {
            return contactDetail;
        }

        public void setContactDetail(ContactDetailBean contactDetail) {
            this.contactDetail = contactDetail;
        }

        public int getCreatedBy() {
            return createdBy;
        }

        public void setCreatedBy(int createdBy) {
            this.createdBy = createdBy;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getLastUpdated() {
            return lastUpdated;
        }

        public void setLastUpdated(String lastUpdated) {
            this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
        }

        public String getDateCreated() {
            return dateCreated;
        }

        public void setDateCreated(String dateCreated) {
            this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        }

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public boolean isDeleted() {
            return deleted;
        }

        public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
            this.deleted = deleted;
        }

        public int getUpdatedBy() {
            return updatedBy;
        }

        public void setUpdatedBy(int updatedBy) {
            this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
        }

        public List<Integer> getCategories() {
            return categories;
        }

        public void setCategories(List<Integer> categories) {
            this.categories = categories;
        }

        public static class ContactDetailBean {

            private Object id;
            private Object emailId;
            private Object phone;
            private Object fax;
            private Object postalCode;
            private Object state;
            private Object longitude;
            private Object latitude;
            private Object addressLine2;
            private Object addressLine1;
            private Object mobile;
            private Object country;
            private Object city;

            public Object getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(Object id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public Object getEmailId() {
                return emailId;
            }

            public void setEmailId(Object emailId) {
                this.emailId = emailId;
            }

            public Object getPhone() {
                return phone;
            }

            public void setPhone(Object phone) {
                this.phone = phone;
            }

            public Object getFax() {
                return fax;
            }

            public void setFax(Object fax) {
                this.fax = fax;
            }

            public Object getPostalCode() {
                return postalCode;
            }

            public void setPostalCode(Object postalCode) {
                this.postalCode = postalCode;
            }

            public Object getState() {
                return state;
            }

            public void setState(Object state) {
                this.state = state;
            }

            public Object getLongitude() {
                return longitude;
            }

            public void setLongitude(Object longitude) {
                this.longitude = longitude;
            }

            public Object getLatitude() {
                return latitude;
            }

            public void setLatitude(Object latitude) {
                this.latitude = latitude;
            }

            public Object getAddressLine2() {
                return addressLine2;
            }

            public void setAddressLine2(Object addressLine2) {
                this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
            }

            public Object getAddressLine1() {
                return addressLine1;
            }

            public void setAddressLine1(Object addressLine1) {
                this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
            }

            public Object getMobile() {
                return mobile;
            }

            public void setMobile(Object mobile) {
                this.mobile = mobile;
            }

            public Object getCountry() {
                return country;
            }

            public void setCountry(Object country) {
                this.country = country;
            }

            public Object getCity() {
                return city;
            }

            public void setCity(Object city) {
                this.city = city;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I called in a Fragment

```
private void loadOrderFeed() {

    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    if (getNetworkAvailability()) {
        getFeed();
    } else {
        getFeedFromDatabase();
    }
}
```

in onCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Returning the layout file after inflating
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recent_order_list, container, false);
    dBhelper = new DBhelper(getActivity(), getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
    try
    {
        dBhelper.prepareDatabase();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    loadOrderFeed();
    return view;


}
```

I am not getting response in response.body() while debugging is there any issue in POJO or the classes are created in one in another is it right?
I am new to android.
Can anybody suggest what to do in this situation?
[image]

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the problem. Whether you get a response or not is not controlled by your POJO

Comment: ya i know but i generated using gson format that's y sometimes we don't get response due to error in json dat's y @cricket_007

Comment: i edited my question can u pls suggest what to do in this situation? @cricket_007

Comment: i added in my question where i called, in onCreateView in a Fragment now i don't unserstand where there is problem getting response? @cricket_007

Comment: I see at least two conditions you can debug. 1) Network is available. Add an `else` and `Log` it. 2) `list.size()` is empty, and you don't do anything otherwise. So, I ask, how do you know it is not getting in there?

Comment: I added another bean class ListBean by using this url  "http://shaoniiuc.com/json_bangla"       I just passed ListBean instead of AssignToBean where i didn't get list.size() as well as response.body()in AssignToBean but the same i got in ListBean?

Comment: as u said i checked network condition but it works fine...  ApiOrderListBean.DataBean.OrdersBean.AssignToBean but i think that assigning bean like this in a list makes the difference, i was not sure about so i asked on SO  can u suggest now?

Comment: sir the code goes to response but list.size() is null even while debugging response.body() is null dat's y and even no warning neither error is shown @cricket_007

Comment: Let me add the screenshot @cricket_007

Comment: I think you mean `list` is null, not `list.size()`. If your list is null, then the POJO is indeed an issue, but that would be GSON's fault, not Retrofit's

Comment: so i should add json in question @cricket_007 ?

Comment: i have converted using GsonLibrary in POJO so acco to u gson is faulty?@cricket_007

Comment: If Gson is unable to convert JSON into Java, it returns null. Please try to generate it again. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: I'll try and ask if issue exists @cricket_007

Comment: I checked on [jsonschema2pojo.org],u were right ,it gave me a diff class of every bean like _assignTo_ and BillingContact etc, so i need to make a diff class of every bean? @cricket_007

Comment: bean == class. Yes

Comment: thank you so much @cricket_007 for answering silly questions of mine..:) god bless.

Comment: So, code works now?

Comment: while debugging it doesn't enter in to onResponse now @cricket_007

Comment: Your `onFailure` is empty. Put something there, please.

Comment: i added in onFailure still not getting in to response @cricket_007

Comment: You said it was not getting in there before, but yet `list` was empty. Therefore it was indeed getting into `onResponse`, so I don't know what you mean anymore

Comment: No this time even it is not showing list.size(); it is not entering in onResponse earlier it was entering now it is not getting response @cricket_007

Comment: do u know how to pass header ? i have added plz check     @GET(Constants.ORDER_LIST_METHOD)
    Call<List<OrderListResponse>> getAllData(@Header("companyid")String access_token);         Call<List<OrderListResponse>> call = ApiClient.getAPIService().getAllData("companyid");  @cricket_007

Comment: If it's not in onResponse, then it must be in onFailure. "CompanyId"  is not a proper HTTP header, anyway... https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header

Comment: As well as I am getting reponse now in onResposne @cricket_007

Comment: Feel free to create your own answer below with your solution to the problem instead of leaving it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding header in retrofitinterface.

Comment: what header you added ?